# PHP/HTML - Display Uploaded Files in List

Tags: php, html, file-upload, image-uploading, file-sharing

I'm trying to create a file sharing site where I can display the links of all uploaded images. Once a user uploads one file, they will be able to both see the files already uploaded and upload another file. However, I'm having two problems at the moment:
1. I don't know how to re-display the main upload page once a user uploads an image.
2. I don't know how to dynamically create links based on the files present.

Here is the code that I have so far:

**HTML/PHP**
    
    
    
    
    File-Sharing Site

```
<body>
<h2>File-Sharing Site</h2>
<h3>Upload file</h3>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Search for file: <br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 800000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

?>

Comment: Your script opens your server to a total compromise. You have pathetically-easy-to-bypass "security". I suggest you kill this code and look for the MANY 'secure upload' script questions + answers on this site.

Comment: This code isn't for commercial purposes. It will not be a public file and security will be coming for other things. For now, I need to figure out how to create a dynamic list in the main file based on what's going on in the file uploading script.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your main page to display uploaded files:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('upload/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry<br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}   
?>
```

Of course you have to redirect back to the main page to see the list of files and possibly upload more files. Or to use ajax to upload files, so that you are not forced to redirect back.

I have used ready made plugin to achieve this all:
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

1) Use [Header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)`header('Location: ... ');` for redirect user to main upload page
2) You need to use *sql solution to store file links and display them.
2a) Give unique file name to all uploaded files(i.e md5($file['name'])

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax file upload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/).
Upload file with ajax, and then return file path as response... Then just print that response as link on page (in some div, field... )

```
 $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:'upload_file.php',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'file',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response)
            {
                $("#div_where_you_print_response").html(response)
            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    );
```